# If a data frame column is a list, extracting elements of the list is giving an error

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I am looking to extract the 0th member of each of the lists using below code:

```
df["column"].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

but I have getting the following error:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: can you show what df["column"] looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is some `NaN`s values.

You can check it:

```
print (df[df["column"].isnull()])

  column
2    NaN
```

So you can use `str[0]`:

```
df["column"].str[0]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[['a','s'],['d'], np.nan, ['s','d','f']]})
print (df)
      column
0     [a, s]
1        [d]
2        NaN
3  [s, d, f]

df['new'] = df["column"].str[0]
print (df)
      column  new
0     [a, s]    a
1        [d]    d
2        NaN  NaN
3  [s, d, f]    s
```

```
print (df["column"].apply(lambda x: x[0]))
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

---

Same error is if `float` as `scalar`s between `list`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[[4.4,7.8],[1], 4.7, [4, 7.4, 1.2]]})
print (df)
          column
0     [4.4, 7.8]
1            [1]
2            4.7
3  [4, 7.4, 1.2]
```

You can check all non `list`s values:

```
print (df[df["column"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float))])

  column
2    4.7
```

Solution is use `if-else` with lambda function:

```
print (df["column"].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, float) else x[0]))
0    4.4
1    1.0
2    4.7
3    4.0
Name: column, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to Python, and you nailed it bang on. There were NaN values in the column. Your response provided a lot of clarity.